# Paypal REST API and Chargebacks/Cancellations

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have been working paypal integration to an existing system of ours and successfully done tests on sandbox by using rest api and express checkouts.

Although documentation is detailed, I couldnt see anything about chargeback (i.e reverse transactions) and cancellations on rest api documentation page http://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

So in case a user buys something successfully and the payment status becomes "completed", then there is a reverse transaction like chargeback, paypal will send a request to the return and cancel urls which are predefined while creating the related payment, or the client application has to check the payment statuses manually by rest calls? Or are there any other configs that I need to send while triggering the very first payment request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to setup [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) to handle that sort of thing.

IPN will automatically POST data about all transactions that hit your PayPal account to a URL you specify.  This URL (a script) can receive the data and update your database, generate email notifications, or anything else you might want to automate based on the transactions.

You can handle all sorts of things with IPN.  For chargebacks specifically, you would receive an IPN with the following params...

- txn_type=new_case
- case_type=chargeback

Of course, you'll get a bunch more parameters, too, but those would be how you can pick out the chargebacks and processing them accordingly.

Comment: thank you :) I was missing the related part for setting the ipn and enabling it on sandbox settings :)